# Jquery - Número SEM arredondamento

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como posso deixar o resultado de uma conta com o resultado inteiro, **sem arredondamento**, ou seja toda vez que o jQuery executa o script ele retorna um valor e cada navegador arredonda de seu modo.

Quero uma forma de deixar o valor inteiro sem arredondamento para todas os navegadores como no exemplo:

Este é o valor real:

`933 / 9 =  103.66666666666666666666666666667`

No navegador:

`933 / 9 = 103.766`

Comment: Não será `103.667` no navegador? E 103.666...7 não é o valor real!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria forçar a quantidade de casas decimais com [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = (933 / 9).toFixed(20); // 103.66666666666667140362
```

Comment: Dessa forma limita os caracteres em 20, quero uma forma que não tenha limite.

Comment: Sem limite não existe nem sequer em papel! É uma dízima infinita https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADzima_peri%C3%B3dica

Answer (score 0):

Ja tentou usar [parseFloat ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) ?

```
var num = parseFloat(933 / 9);

console.log (num) // 103.66666666666667
```

Ou você pode usar como **Lucas C.** disse mas com valor máximo, assim:

```
var num = (933 / 9).toFixed(100);
console.log (num); // 103.6666666666666714036182384006679058074951171875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Usando valor máximo da função [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) (0 a 100).